# Получить строку между определенными символами

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть, к примеру, некая строка, например `my::name::space` из которой мне нужно получить три строки разделенные `::`. Как это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений в `c++`? Подобрал такую конструкцию как:

```
(?<=::)(.+)(?=::)
```

Но сдесь сразу несколько проблем:

1) При запуске вылетает `core dump` из-за `?<=`. Так если заменяю на `?=` то все работает (хотя и не верно, выводит первые `::`).
2) Такая конструкция не выведет первую и последнюю строку. Как добавить условие на начало/завершение строки (вроде `?=::|$` - только это не работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так

```
(?:::)(\w+)(?:::)|^(\w+)|(\w+)$
```

1. либо слово, окружённое `::` (при этом :: в незахватывающих группах)
2. либо слово с начала
3. либо слово с конца

Comment: Спасибо, выражение верное, но, к сожалению, с++ почему-то упорно не желает иметь дело с последовательностью `?<=` считая, что `<` это открытая последовательность

Comment: а почему отредактривали обратно? Это регулярное выражение не соответствует условию, так как захватывает `::`? Правильным будет `(?!::)(\w+)(?=::)|^(\w+)|(\w+)$`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch под своими постами комменты можно писать вне зависимости от текущей репутации. Править свои посты - тем более. Это ответ user337494. Если он посчитает нужным - зарегистрируется и исправит код. Если у вас есть более правильный вариант решения - оформите его отдельным ответом. Справка ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  - это про ответы на свои вопросы, а не про правку чужих :)

Comment: @PashaPash слушайте, я серьезно не понимаю в чем проблема: в данном виде выражение не верное, так как не соответствует условию, но это несоответствие фиксится всего 2-мя символами!!! А что касается о том, править ответ или нет - так почему бы не самому отвечающему решить: откатывать изменения, или нет?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Почитайте, пожалуйста, справку, раздел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing. Там даже специально выделено "без *изменения* его смысла". Поменять код в ответе на другой - это, очевидно, изменение смысла ответа. Это ответ за авторством конкретного участника. Выражение не соответствует условию - ок, напишите про это в комментарии. Отвечающий сам решит, вносить в *свой* ответ ваши изменения, или нет. Считаете что нужно разрешить править чужие сообщения без ограничений? Создайте про это топик на мете, и если сможете убедить достаточно много участников - правила поменяют.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch по поводу конкретно этого ответа - автор специально выделил `::` в non-captured group (`?:`) и специально упомянул об этом в ответе. Его ответ захватывает `name` в качестве значения второй группы. Что прекрасно [видно в песочнице](https://regex101.com/r/FVay5x/1/). Просто вы почему-то смотрите на Full Match. А надо смотреть на значение группы. А ваша правка делает его примечание "(при этом :: в незахватывающих группах)" бессмысленным - т.к. незахватывающие группы вы из кода выбросили.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93472/discussion-between-pashapash-and-andrej-levkovitch).